# Manage files on c++ (read)

Tags: file, c++11

Why when I try read my archived it don't register my values in the value of my program?

This is my code:

```
void db::cargar(){
    l.open("db.txt", ios::binary);
    if(!l){
        cout << "No se puede abrir la base de datos" << endl;
    }else{
        cout << "Carga exitosa!!!" << endl;
        l.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&a), sizeof(a));
        while(!l.eof()){
            cout << a << endl << endl;
            l.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&a), sizeof(a));
        }
    }
    l.close();
}
```

This function is for read the file in my cpp, but when I go to view my method doesn't appear the information of my file

```
void db::mostrar(){
    temp = primero;
    if(!primero){
        cout << "No hay trabajos registrados" << endl;
    }else{
        while(temp != 0){
            a = temp->getD();
            cout << a << endl << endl;
            temp = temp->getP();
        }
    }
}
```

whit this function should appear the information of my file, but doesn't appear.

Help me, plis!!